# SQLalchemy AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add an item to my database with SQLAlchemy + Python, but keep getting an error.

My database_setup.py:

```
class company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    compID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable = False)

class item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    itemID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    category = Column(String(250))
    description = Column(String(250))
    price = Column(String(8))
    compID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.compID'))
    company = relationship(company)
```

after importing sqlalchemy to my terminal, I define an item to insert:

```
JawboneUP3 = item(
    itemID="1",
    name="Jawbone UP3",
    description="The latest UP!", 
    category="tracker",
    price="$174.99",
    company="Jawbone"
)
```

and draw a session to add and commit:

```
session.add(JawboneUP3)
session.commit()
```

When I submit, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1399, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1417, in _save_or_update_state
    halt_on=self._contains_state):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2037, in cascade_iterator
    parent_dict, visited_states, halt_on))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py", line 932, in cascade_iterator
    get_all_pending(state, dict_)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 761, in get_all_pending
   ret = [(instance_state(current), current)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

I have added a 'Jawbone' object to my company table, that I understand my 'JawboneUP3' should relate back to. This object was added correctly through a browser form that I enabled via my webserver script. I believe I should be able to add items right from the terminal though.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you are defining the related company schema:

```
JawboneUP3 = item(itemID = "1", name = "Jawbone UP3", description = "The latest UP!", 
                  category = "tracker", price = "$174.99", company = "Jawbone")
                                                           # HERE^
```

The `item` constructor expects a `company` instance but you are passing a string value. Fix it:

```
JawboneUP3 = item(itemID="1", 
                  name="Jawbone UP3", 
                  description="The latest UP!", 
                  category="tracker", 
                  price="$174.99", 
                  company=company(name="Jawbone"))
```

Answer (score 15):

First of all, when defining a class in Python, it is of good  practice to to start the names with an uppercase letter like this:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    compID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable = False)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    itemID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    category = Column(String(250))
    description = Column(String(250))
    price = Column(String(8))
    compID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.compID'))
    company = relationship(company)
```

That being said, it is not why your code throws an error. :)

### The reason

The `Item` constructor expects an instance of the object `Company` to by passed as a value of the variable `company`

#### Solution 1: The *Jawbone* company does not exist in your database

Here the answer of @alecxe is valid.

You should replace your code with:

```
JawboneUP3 = Item(itemID="1", 
                  name="Jawbone UP3", 
                  description="The latest UP!", 
                  category="tracker", 
                  price="$174.99", 
                  company=company(name="Jawbone"))
```

Adding this object to the session and comiting the changes will actually make two entries to your database:

- The item entry, with name "Jawbone UP3"
- A row in the *company* database, a company with name "Jawbone"

#### Solution 2: The *Jawbone* company exists in your database

Here you should fetch the company *Jawbone* from your table "company" and pass it as an argument to the `Item` constructor, like this:

```
jawbone = session.query(Company).filter_by(name="Jawbone").first()

JawboneUP3 = Item(itemID="1", 
                  name="Jawbone UP3", 
                  description="The latest UP!", 
                  category="tracker", 
                  price="$174.99", 
                  company=jawbone)
```

For the `session` part check [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do)

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,redirect,render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students1.sqlite3'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Categ(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(100))
    product=db.relationship('Product',backref='owner',lazy=True)

class Product(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    pname=db.Column(db.String(100))
    price=db.Column(db.Integer)
    categ_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('categ.id'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'home'

@app.route('/post',methods=['POST','GET'])
def Productform():
    ob=Categ.query.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        owner=request.form['ca']
        user = Categ.query.filter_by(name=owner).first()

        user=Product(pname=request.form['pname'],price=request.form['price'],owner=user)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return 'submit'

    return render_template('product.html',ob=ob)



@app.route('/categ',methods=['POST','GET'])
def Categoryform():
    if request.method=='POST':
        user=Categ(name=request.form['cname'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return 'submit'

    return render_template('categ.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
   db.create_all()
```