# flask wtforms sqlalchemy AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to send form data in a sqlite database. There are 6 tables with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships between them.

Here's my model:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    activities = db.relationship('Activity', backref='event', lazy='dynamic')
    participants = db.relationship('User', backref='event', lazy='dynamic')
    globalweights = db.relationship('Globalw8', backref='event', lazy='dynamic')


relationship_table = db.Table('relationship_table', db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False), db.Column('activity_id', db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('activity.id'),nullable=False), db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'activity_id'))


class Activity(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), nullable=False)
    participants = db.relationship('User', secondary=relationship_table, backref='activity')
    amounts = db.relationship('Amount', backref='activity', lazy='dynamic')
    activityweights = db.relationship('Activityw8', backref='activity', lazy='dynamic')


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), nullable=False)
    globalw8_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('globalw8.id'), nullable=False)
    activityweights = db.relationship('Activityw8', backref='participant', lazy='dynamic')
    amounts = db.relationship('Amount', backref='participant', lazy='dynamic')


class Amount(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    activity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('activity.id'), nullable=False)


class Globalw8(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    weight = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), nullable=False)


class Activityw8(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    weight = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    activity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('activity.id'), nullable=False)
```

And here's my route:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = eveForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        activity = Activity(name=form.actName.data, event=form.eveName.data)
        event = Event(name=form.eveName.data)
        user = User(name=form.partName.data, event=form.eveName.data, globalw8=form.partGlobWeight.data, activity=form.actName.data)
        globalw8 = Globalw8(weight=form.partGlobWeight.data, participant=form.partName.data, event=form.eveName.data)
        amount = Amount(amount=form.amount.data, participant=form.partName.data, activity=form.actName.data)
        activityw8 = Activityw8(weight=form.partActWeight.data, participant=form.partName.data, activity=form.actName.data)
        db.session.add(activityw8)
        db.session.add(activity)
        db.session.add(event)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.add(globalw8)
        db.session.add(amount)
        db.session.commit()
```

When I submit my form I get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'"

I suspect this is due to my route and how I am trying to collect the form data, in particular data related to relationships 
*(ex. user = User(name=form.partName.data, event=form.eveName.data, globalw8=form.partGlobWeight.data, activity=form.actName.data)*

For instance in the example above, *event* is a backref and nowhere have I found what to affect to it but what I have done, i.e. *form.eveName.data*

Thanks in advance

Edit: Here's the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\code\Flaskapps\cuentapp\app.py", line 70, in home
    activity = Activity(name=form.actName.data, event=form.eveName.data)
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__

  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 441, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 129, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 438, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\base.py", line 836, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 262, in __set__
    instance_state(instance), instance_dict(instance), value, None
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 975, in set
    value = self.fire_replace_event(state, dict_, value, old, initiator)
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 998, in fire_replace_event
    state, value, previous, initiator or self._replace_token
  File "C:\Users\xaray\Anaconda3\envs\Flask\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 1407, in emit_backref_from_scalar_set_event
    instance_state(child),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Comment: Please tell on which variable this error occurs. A complete copy of the error trail would be better.

Comment: I've just edited my post with the traceback; if I understand it correctly, it looks related to *activity = Activity(name=form.actName.data, event=form.eveName.data)*

Comment: You could try the solution applied here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083772/sqlalchemy-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state

Comment: Well I have already tried everything I could find on stackoverflow or youtube tutorials that seemed related to my issue, and nothing have worked so far. Thanks anyway. In fact I think I would be interested to hear from someone who has dealt with sqlalchemy many-to-many relationships + wtforms, to see what their code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue 1

I think you have overly specified relationships ([In SQL, is it OK for two tables to refer to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446641/in-sql-is-it-ok-for-two-tables-to-refer-to-each-other)):

```
class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    globalw8_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('globalw8.id'), nullable=False)

class Globalw8(db.Model):
    # ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

You can replace this with a relationship, thereby requiring only one FK input:

```
class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    globalw8 = db.relationship('GlobalW8', back_populates='user')

class Globalw8(db.Model):
    # ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship('GlobalW8', back_populates='globalw8')
```

Now when you create SQLAlchemy object entities they are `transient` meaning they do not acquire their associated `id` from the database before they are committed to the database. But you cannot commit them to the database because you will break the `nullable=False` constraint. So you need to add them, flush the database to 'act as if commiting but not actually commit' and then re populate info and then commit:

eg.

```
new_user = User(..)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.flush()
new_globalw8 = Globalw8(.., user_id=new_user.id)
db.session.add(new_globalw8)
db.session.commit()
```

*Note this might break some inherent database integrity changing it away from your original structure, so you might want to experiment.*

## Issue 2

This is actually your specific stack trace error:

```
File "C:\Users\xaray\code\Flaskapps\cuentapp\app.py", line 70, in home
    activity = Activity(name=form.actName.data, event=form.eveName.data)
..
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'**
```

What this is saying is that because of the line:

```
activities = db.relationship('Activity', backref='event', lazy='dynamic')
```

then `Activity.event` is expecting to be an `SQLAlchemy Instance State`. However, you are supplying it a string from your form: `form.eveName.data`, which is completely incompatible. What you should really do is create the `Event` first:

```
new_event = Event(name=form.eveName.data)
```

and then populate that as the event for activities.

```
activity = Activity(name=form.actName.data, event=new_event)
```

*Note you may get a transient error if you do not flush the database (akin to above), but perhaps not - its been a while since I did this*.