# SQLAlchemy: Assign value to a relationship column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have defined these SQLAlchemy models:

```py
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primar_key=True)
    pets = db.relationship("Pet", backref="person", lazy=True)

class Pet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primar_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    person = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"))
```

I'm trying to assign/overwrite a `Person.pets` for later use (but not updating the value in db).

```py
person_with_temporary_pet = {1: ["Max", "Charlie", "Cooper"], 2: ["Buddy", "Rocky", "Millo"]}
overwrited_person = []

for id, name in person_with_temporary_pet.items():
    person = Person.query.get(id)
    person.pets = name
    overwrited_person.append(person)
```

This would result in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`

---

FYI would like to dump `overwrited_person` into Marshmallow Schema:

```py
class PersonSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

person_schema = PersonSchema(many=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your pets relation in wrong class, you need to put it in Pet class itself. and the **person_obj.pets** contains a **list of Pet objects** and you are trying to assign it the **list of strings**. To work in your scenario you can change your for loop code as below:

```
for id, name in person_with_temporary_pet.items():
    person = Person.query.get(id)
    person.pets = Pet.query.filter(Pet.name.in_(name)).all()
    overwrited_person.append(person)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083772/sqlalchemy-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state).

In your case, you are defining the Pets schema inside Person but trying to pass an array of strings values instead of a object.